# Is it possible to set role in FreeIPA to use for applications as Jenkins, Github?

Tags: jenkins, github, role-based-access-control

LDAP in FreeIPA, it can create groups, roles and set permissions. Applications such as Jenkins, Github also has roles feature.

2 questions:

1. Can roles feature be used in every application? (At least Jenkins and Github may use groups feature in LDAP)
2. If want to control several users can access Jenkins, several users can access Github, is it possible to control it in LDAP side? If deploy multiple LDAP server for different applications will realize it, but that's complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your title, no.

1. It's impossible to quantify if every application has this capability. Many do.
2. Users/Groups in Jenkins OSS map back to LDAP but you control the permissions via Jenkins.

[image]

As you can see above Users/Groups have specific permissions that are specified/controlled in Jenkins. If this group exists in LDAP (xxx) the users in this group get the permission you setup in Jenkins. This makes it easier then managing individuals.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer!